# Открыть одну страницу только на двух компьютерах

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, как сделать так чтобы определенная страница на сайте могла открыться только на 2 компьютерах. По какому принципу можно осуществить привязку? По ip не подходит. Веб-приложение на php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создавать **хеш** (md5, sha, ...), состоящий из расширения экрана, браузера, ОС, IP -- это будет уникальный идентификатор пользователя.

[Тут](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/id) описаны альтернативные способы идентификации

[PHP: Информация о посетителе сайта](http://www.gcmsite.ru/?pg=art&id=php-people-information)

Comment: И типа, если кто-то сменит экран, то работа зафейлится?

Comment: это не уникальный, разрешение, ос и браузер могут быть у каждого одинаковый, ip с одной сети тоже могут быть одинаковыми, шанс конечно минимален, но все же, спасибо за пример

Comment: спасибо за статьи

Comment: @benjibboy, возможно сделать полный клон клиента, вплоть до подмены MAC-адреса. Разве что сетчатку глаза сканировать через веб-камеру :-). Тут все упирается в вероятность совпадения. При добавлении одного параметра вероятность уменьшается в разы. Вы уж решите какая вероятность для вас достаточна.

Comment: @cadmy, при изменении любого параметра естественно пользователь определяется как новый. Зато вероятность совпадения уменьшается. Это уже решать реализатору, что важнее.

Comment: getenv("HTTP_REFERER") передает с какой страницы мы пришли? Тогда если сделать страницу А, на нее поставить пароль и логин, после авторизации идет ссылка и переходим на страницу Б по этой ссылке. На странице Б проверка, если переход не по ссылке со странице а, то нет доступа, правильно ведь я описал? Получается только те кто зайдет на страницу А смогут попасть на страницу Б

Comment: @benjibboy, Вы понимаете, что в этом случае должны совпадать одновременно все параметры? Это редкий случай!

Comment: блин это же просто авторизация, которую без страницы А можно сделать на странице Б)) ладно, спасибо, буду думать как лучше

Comment: Тогда уж заводите таблицу пользователей и создавайте регистрацию/авторизацию.